# Return a boolean in a mysql function and use it in python

Tags: python, mysql

So what I need is return a boolean in a MySQL's function and use it in Python as condition in a Python's function. I have this

```
class A:
def login():
    username: input("Username: ")
    password: input("Password: ")
    if B.user_exists(username, password):
        # do something
```

and

```
class B:
def user_exists(cls, username, password):
    try:
        db = cls.conection()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT UserExists(%s, %s)", (username, password))
        # here it should be something to return if it's true or false
    Error:
        print("Error", Error)
```

Note: the MySQL's function works fine and I tested it on Datagrip, so that's not the problem

Comment: https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#some-examples `cursor.fetchone()[0]` should contain what you need

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem. Thanks @mrEvgenX